# XP Pen Deco V1 02 changing behavior and freezing

Tags: sculpting

I have my XP Pen set up for the buttons to emulate right and middle click. Seemingly at random, when I'm sculpting, blender will freeze and then the button behavior changes. One of them emulates the left-click, while the other one will only do a box select.

I've read through dozens of reddit and forum posts and haven't found anyone with this exact issue, but I have followed the troubleshooting steps of the posts with similar issues to no avail. The thing that came closest to working was completely disabling Windows Ink in the registry (which messed up my pen pressure for Krita, but oh well). That made it better, the problem occurs less frequently, but it still occurs.

The workaround is easy. Just close the Pentablet app and restart it, but that's annoying. I know others have had success with XP Pen. I believe it's what Grant Abbitt uses (not the same model).

I haven't nailed down anything specific that sends it into this freakout state, but I believe I'm beginning to notice a pattern around navigation. Like, if I am holding the button to rotate around for too long, or if I accidentally hit both the buttons on the pen at the same time. That's not set in stone though, just something I believe I'm picking up on.